# Dependency 'fr.mrmicky:fastboard:1.2.1' not found

Tags: javascript, minecraft, spigot

In my pom.xml file I'm having issues getting the fastboard integration (I am using Maven).

My pom:

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                        <outputFile>C:\Users\brdwl\Desktop\Server - Plugin Test\plugins\MyFirstPlugin.jar</outputFile>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <relocations>
                    <relocation>
                        <pattern>fr.mrmicky.fastboard</pattern>
                        <!-- Replace 'com.yourpackage' with the package of your plugin ! -->
                        <shadedPattern>com.FirstPlugin.fastboard</shadedPattern>
                    </relocation>
                </relocations>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spigotmc-repo</id>
        <url>https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>sonatype</id>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
        <artifactId>spigot-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>fr.mrmicky</groupId>
        <artifactId>fastboard</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

For reference, [here](https://github.com/MrMicky-FR/FastBoard) is the github page of what I'm trying to install.

When adding these details in the following turns red and says `Dependency 'fr.mrmicky:fastboard:1.2.1' not found` - **EDIT - Added full console logs to the OP, it no longer shows up in red inside the pom, but still unable to access it.**

I've confirmed that it is the correct version that is on the github.

```xml
<groupId>fr.mrmicky</groupId>
<artifactId>fastboard</artifactId>
<version>1.2.1</version>
```

Console output during the rebuild is this:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for FirstPlugin:FirstPlugin:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.(groupId:artifactId)' must be unique but found duplicate declaration of plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin @ line 49, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------------------< FirstPlugin:FirstPlugin >-----------------------
[INFO] Building FirstPlugin 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ FirstPlugin ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ FirstPlugin ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ FirstPlugin ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ FirstPlugin ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ FirstPlugin ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ FirstPlugin ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Users\brdwl\IdeaProjects\MyFirstPlugin\target\FirstPlugin-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-shade-plugin:3.3.0:shade (default) @ FirstPlugin ---
[INFO] Including fr.mrmicky:fastboard:jar:1.2.1 in the shaded jar.
[WARNING] FirstPlugin-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar, fastboard-1.2.1.jar define 1 overlapping resource: 
[WARNING]   - META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
[WARNING] maven-shade-plugin has detected that some class files are
[WARNING] present in two or more JARs. When this happens, only one
[WARNING] single version of the class is copied to the uber jar.
[WARNING] Usually this is not harmful and you can skip these warnings,
[WARNING] otherwise try to manually exclude artifacts based on
[WARNING] mvn dependency:tree -Ddetail=true and the above output.
[WARNING] See https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ FirstPlugin ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\brdwl\IdeaProjects\MyFirstPlugin\target\FirstPlugin-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to C:\Users\brdwl\.m2\repository\FirstPlugin\FirstPlugin\1.0-SNAPSHOT\FirstPlugin-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\brdwl\IdeaProjects\MyFirstPlugin\pom.xml to C:\Users\brdwl\.m2\repository\FirstPlugin\FirstPlugin\1.0-SNAPSHOT\FirstPlugin-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.549 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-04-17T12:29:48+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Apologies, I've changed it now! Thanks for the help guides!

Comment: Can you post the complete error?

Comment: Added full console logs to the OP, it no longer shows up in red inside the pom, but still unable to access it.